# FindControl() method for Dynamically Nested Controls on PostBack

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How do you get a specific nested control of dynamically created controls (i.e. the child of a dynamic control)? The FindControl() method does not work because it only deals with TopLevel dynamic controls I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to recurse through your controls: (C# code)

```
   public static Control FindControl(Control parentControl, string fieldName)
    {
        if (parentControl != null && parentControl.HasControls())
        {
            Control c = parentControl.FindControl(fieldName);
            if (c != null)
            {
                return c;
            }

            // if arrived here, then not found on this level, so search deeper

            // loop through collection
            foreach (Control ctrl in parentControl.Controls)
            {
                // any child controls?
                if (ctrl.HasControls())
                {
                    // try and find there
                    Control c2 = FindControl(ctrl, fieldName);
                    if (c2 != null)
                    {
                        return c2; // found it!
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null; // found nothing (in this branch)
    }
```

Comment: thanx. This works for both [ClientID] and [ID] in the fieldName parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension method I've used in times past.  I've found that using it as an extension method makes the code a little more expressive, but that's just preference.

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension method that will recursively search the control's children for a control with the given ID.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parent">The control who's children should be searched</param>
/// <param name="controlID">The ID of the control to find</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Control FindControlRecursive(this Control parent, string controlID)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(parent.ClientID) && parent.ClientID.Equals(controlID)) return parent;

    System.Web.UI.Control control = null;
    foreach (System.Web.UI.Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        control = c.FindControlRecursive(controlID);
        if (control != null)
            break;
    }
    return control;
}
```

Comment: @jamar777 thanx, This works if you pass the conrol.ID but not for control.ClientId. since i'm trying to find a child of an instance of a user_control (i.e. several instances of same user_control) i have to use the ClientID.

Comment: Can't you jsut update the code then to compare against control.ClientID?

Comment: Just updated code example to compare against ClientID, rather than ID

Comment: @jamar777 thanx for update. I did try but it still didn't find. Maybe becaue the passed client id for example is like(ctl03$RemoveButton). Not sure if this is why though.